# Particles movement with spin -1,+1 in a square in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have a particle that moves in a square with spin -1 and +1. I want to create a matrix in R in order to register the following directions:

The matrix must have number of columns L = 4, row  N = L*L,
and must go for i in range N:

right:  `((i %/% L) * L + (i + 1) %% L,` 
down :      `(i + L) %% N,` 
left:     `(i %/% L) * L + (i - 1) %% L,` 
up:    `(i - L) %% N)`

where  `%%`  is the modulo operator and   `%/%`  the floor division (  `%/%`  is the integer division but I do not know if there is an operator in R for floor division)

```
 (1, 4, 3, 12),
 (2, 5, 0, 13),
 (3, 6, 1, 14),
 (0, 7, 2, 15),
 (5, 8, 7, 0),
 (6, 9, 4, 1),
 (7, 10, 5, 2),
 (4, 11, 6, 3),
 (9, 12, 11, 4),
 (10, 13, 8, 5),
 (11, 14, 9, 6),
 (8, 15, 10, 7),
 (13, 0, 15, 8),
 (14, 1, 12, 9),
 (15, 2, 13, 10),
 (12, 3, 14, 11)
```

How can I do it in R ?
Any help ?

In python  this is done with:

```
L = 4
N = L*L
neighbors = {i : ((i // L) * L + (i + 1) % L,   # RIGHT
                 (i + L) % N,                   # DOWN
                 (i // L) * L + (i - 1) % L,    # LEFT
                 (i - L) % N)                   # UP
                 for i in range(N)}
neighbors
```

But how this can be implemented in R?

Comment: @JohnColeman no is the same It was a typo.I edited it.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first the variables are defined:

- c = L = no. of columns
- r = N = no of rows

Then a Null-matrix is defined and the matrix is filled according to your formulas.

```r
c <- 4; r <- N <- 16; L <- 4
AA = matrix (nr= r, nc=c, 0)
for (i in 0:15){
    AA[i+1,1] = (i %/% L) * L + (i + 1) %% L
    AA[i+1,2] = (i + L) %% N
    AA[i+1,3] = (i %/% L) * L + (i - 1) %% L
    AA[i+1,4] = (i - L) %% N
}
AA
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#>  [1,]    1    4    3   12
#>  [2,]    2    5    0   13
#>  [3,]    3    6    1   14
#>  [4,]    0    7    2   15
#>  [5,]    5    8    7    0
#>  [6,]    6    9    4    1
#>  [7,]    7   10    5    2
#>  [8,]    4   11    6    3
#>  [9,]    9   12   11    4
#> [10,]   10   13    8    5
#> [11,]   11   14    9    6
#> [12,]    8   15   10    7
#> [13,]   13    0   15    8
#> [14,]   14    1   12    9
#> [15,]   15    2   13   10
#> [16,]   12    3   14   11
```

Comment: @`Homer Jay Simpson` you have your 4 formulas and therefore `L = 4`. For each row `i` the 4 formulas are calculated. The matrix has 16 rows, but counting starts at `0`. This is because in your example the first row obviously has index `i = 0`. As the matrix starts with row 1, the index in the `loop` is `0:15`. You could write instead `0:N-1` which makes it a bit more general.